# Compare all elements of a vector not in a loop

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, vector, compare

I have a vector of natural numbers "New" of SIZE=1000. I would like to create a matrix A, where the element A(i,j)=1 if New(i)>New(j), and 0 otherwise. I have done this using loops:

```
A=zeros(SIZE,SIZE);
for i=1:SIZE
  for j=1:SIZE
    if New(i)>New(j)
        A(i,j)=1;
    end   
  end
end
```

Could anyone suggest any faster and shorter way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a clear case for [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
A = bsxfun(@gt, New(:), New(:).');
```

Comment: So easy! Thank you. I tried this, but without .' and it did not work (

Comment: you can even skip the `(:)`: you don't really care if `New` is a column vector or a row vector.

Comment: @Shai You're right, thanks! In this case there's symmetry. Changed

Comment: @Shai ...on second thought, the `(:)` is needed, because it's `@gt`, not `@eq`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `repmat`

```
 A = repmat(New(:),1,numel(New)) > repmat(New(:)',numel(New),1);
```

Though it is slower than `bsxfun` approach